# How to move text up without increasing picture size

Tags: html, css

I would Like the text to be at the very top and the paragraphs in the center, I tried moving it but, every time I add a margin-bottom it increases the size of my background-image. if I use any other property then It wont move the text, please help, thank you!

```css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Elephant, sans-serif;
  }

 img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  
  
   /* ====== About ====== */

 #about {
   max-width: 100%;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/zpwqaEG.jpg);
   padding: 350px 0;
 }

  .aboutHead {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 64px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #993b3b;


  }
```

```html
<section id="about">
        <h1 class="aboutHead">Our Focus</h1>
        <p class="about1">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p class="about2">
          Nullam ultrices euismod suscipit. Integer vitae massa quam.
          Maecenas tristique vitae mi sit amet rutrum.
          Etiam fringilla justo vitae felis tempus volutpat.
          Phasellus urna ante, porttitor iaculis mattis id, suscipit ul
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
   </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
  <section id="about">
        <h1 class="aboutHead">Our Focus</h1>
    <div class="cdesc">
        <p class="about1">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p class="about2">
          Nullam ultrices euismod suscipit. Integer vitae massa quam.
          Maecenas tristique vitae mi sit amet rutrum.
          Etiam fringilla justo vitae felis tempus volutpat.
          Phasellus urna ante, porttitor iaculis mattis id, suscipit ul
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>
   </section>
```

Stylesheet

```
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Elephant, sans-serif;
  }

 img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

.cdesc {
  padding:350px 0;
}

   /* ====== About ====== */
.about1 {

}

 #about {
   text-align:center;
   max-width: 100%;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/zpwqaEG.jpg);
 }

  .aboutHead {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    font-size: 64px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #993b3b;
```

Comment: This actually worked, I've tested and it works idk why, but  when I tried it out it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using css Flex ? Below are my simple flex box code to make the top tittle at the top and the paragraph centered ?

```
.img-div { 

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    ...

}

.paragraph-div {

    margin: auto

}
```

My codepen

https://codepen.io/ShadowLegend/pen/eeYQrg

Comment: it does works and i copy this from your code above [ https://codepen.io/ShadowLegend/pen/LOYvEg ]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this solution.
I just added absolute positioned wrapper for pragraphs, to align them right in the center of the section. Check it please, maybe this solution fit your needs.

Anyway, it's not a very unified solution, because if you decrease browser size, absolute positioned wrapper may overlap other elements on the page.

```
.paragraphs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
 }
```

[DEMO Codepen](https://codepen.io/faeton/pen/EbxrKq)